# Compare Min value Entity Framework & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have many warehouses, each of them has a delivery time, how do I compare 2 warehouses and return the warehouse with the lowest delivery time?

For example, I get warehouse id 1 and id 2, and I need to compare them.

I tried to write a foreach to match the two ids, but it did not compare, only  return the deadline of the last id run.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25XfL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple console application to show you my approach:

Entity:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Warehouse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DeliveryTime { get; set; }

        public Warehouse(int id, int deliveryTime)
        {
            Id = id;
            DeliveryTime = deliveryTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Service
    {
        public IQueryable<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }
        public Service(int quantity)
        {
            var list = new List<Warehouse>();
            var random = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
            {
                list.Add((new Warehouse(i, random.Next(1, 100))));
            }
            Warehouses = list.AsQueryable();
        }

        public Warehouse GetQuickestWarehouse(int a, int b)
        {
            return Warehouses.Where(w => w.Id == a || w.Id == b).OrderBy(w => w.DeliveryTime).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var service = new Service(100);
            var a = service.Warehouses.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == 1);
            var b = service.Warehouses.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == 2);
            var min = service.GetQuickestWarehouse(a.Id, b.Id);

            Console.WriteLine($"Deliverytime for a: {a.DeliveryTime}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Deliverytime for b: {b.DeliveryTime}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Quickest Warehouse has Id: {min.Id} with delivery time: {min.DeliveryTime}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course constructor in my entity model and my service are only for the console application to work, replace with your own database context and logic. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the warehouse ids, add them to a list

```
var Ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
```

Then use the list to filter the EF warehouses.

Either get the lowest delivery date by OrderBy

```
var lowest = db.Warehouse.Where(w=> Ids.Contains(w.Id)).OrderBy(a => a.DeliveryTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or, by the lowest date value

```
var date = db.Warehouse.Min(a => a.DeliveryTime);
var lowest = db.Warehouse.FirstOrDefault(a =>  Ids.Contains(a.Id) && DateTime.Equals(a.DeliveryTime,date));
```